# Change AJAX jQuery url from checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, checkbox

I have four checkboxes and I am retrieving some JSON data from an API using jQuery AJAX, and I want to change the URL dynamically on checkbox selection. When I put the ajax code inside click function, it's working, but from outside click function it's not working. In fact I can't access category array outside the click function.

I want to store the value of category to a global variable or array, So I can access it in Ajax code or somewhere else in my code and I can't figure out how to do that.

```js
var category = [];
$(".ckbox").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    category.push($(this).val());
  } else {
    var x = category.indexOf($(this).val());
    category.splice(x, 1);
  }
  console.log(category); //show array on checkbox clicking
});
console.log(category); //show empty array

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://godrejapi-dot-indiacomapi.appspot.com/_ah/api/godrej/v1/godrejestablishment?',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    category: category,
    city: 'PUNE',
    begin: '0',
    limit: '200',
  },
  traditional: true,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    alert("something went wrong.");
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeping `ajax` outside `click` function?  There has to be some source point to trigger `ajax` right? Either in any event or function or it will execute in `DOM ready`. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: If you don't run it in an event handler, it just runs once when the page loads. How can it make use of the checkboxes that the user has selected if it runs before the user has had a chance to select something?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with your variable's scope.
Without seeing the entire code, I can't confirm this.
If you want to make sure that the category variable is global, add it to the window object.

```
window.category = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger in event handler to fill your global variable or pass local variable between functions.

```
window.cat = "";

function show(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
};

function run(categoryInner, f) {
  // You can use window.cat instead of categoryInner but you need to check value.
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://godrejapi-dot-indiacomapi.appspot.com/_ah/api/godrej/v1/godrejestablishment?',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      category: categoryInner,
      city: 'PUNE',
      begin: '0',
      limit: '200',
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      f(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("something went wrong.");
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

$(".ckbox").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    category.push($(this).val());
  } else {
    var x = category.indexOf($(this).val());
    category.splice(x, 1);
  }
  window.cat = category;
  run(category, show);
});
```